# Draw Line from Point to existing Line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I am working on a water network, I want to draw a House Connection pipe from a house meter to nearest existing water line, I tried using python script, I could just find the nearest line. I also want a line drawn from Point to nearest water network. Can I get a part of script which draw all the house connection lines automatically with existing nearest water line?

I am working on ArcGIS 10.2.

Comment: -1 I don't see any efforts from your side

Comment: I tried to make a tool using python. It just finds the nearest pipeline. I want new line connection in my network.

Comment: Assign your meters unique ID if absent. Use NEAR tool with near point_X and Y option. Export table and use this fields to AddXY points. Merge them with meters. Use points to line tool with meterID as line ID to convert points to line. Update your Q and I'll upvote it

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this method and below tool also. This method does a problem where House meters are too close to each other.

Answer (score 3):

[**ArcGIS for Water Utilities**](http://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/water/help/network-editing/) is a free add-on from Esri for ArcGIS Desktop that offers tools for working with water networks.

There are two tools in ArcGIS for Water utilities - **Add Laterals at Connections** and **Add Laterals from Line Locations** which would do what you're wanting (from slightly different starting points).

We use this in the office daily and it works well.

You can also have it override the "nearest water line" by selecting a specific line and holding down a set key (Control I think) and then your connections will draw to the selected line instead.

Comment: I want lateral line on every house connection with nearest pipeline.

Comment: This tool can do that.  It will require you to configure it (you'll need to tell it what the Connection point, lateral, and pipeline layers are called)

Comment: Should I tell it using config file or I can directly input these layers in tool?

Comment: in the config file