# ArcMap, creating lines from a set of points that connect to the other line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, line, points-to-line

I have a bunch of points lining up on one side of the highway.

[image]

I would like to create line from each point that reaches to the other side of the highway. The line should be (almost) perpendicular to both sides of the roads. Or, at least it connects the shortest distance between highways. I would also like to let the newly created lines to have the same attribute fields of the points.

Can anyone give me some inputs?

Comment: How many are you talking about?

Comment: about 175 points

Comment: There is a tool in Esri's water network editing add-in that draws lines from existing points to nearby lines. It's reasonably configurable and can copy attributes as well. The reason I asked how many was that it can take a little bit to setup

Comment: This is near duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201867/create-a-line-perpendicular-to-an-existing-line-in-arcgis/201871#201871

Comment: Perhaps use combination of near and point s to line

Comment: As @FelixIP mentioned, use Generate Near Table and check Location (optional) box. This will give you FROM_X, FROM_Y, NEAR_X, and NEAR_Y fields. Then use XY to Line inputting the appropriate fields and setting the Spatial Refernence.

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182941/draw-line-from-point-to-existing-line/182954#182954 - I know this is water network, but still drawing points to lines.  Doesn't need to be in a water network to run.

Comment: @Clubdebambos I think your comment with a link to the documentation of the two tools you mention would be fine as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Generate Near Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm) and check on the Location (optional box), set your points as the input and the lines as the Near features. This will produce a table with FROM_X, FROM_Y, NEAR_X, and NEAR_Y fields.

[image]

Then use [XY To Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/xy-to-line.htm) using the fields from the Generate Near Table

[image]

This will create a feature class connecting the points to the lines.